# MySQL: is there a way to update a many to many join table without getting really granular?

Tags: mysql, go

I have a problem in which I have a M:M relationship between two tables, with a join table storing each of their ids as a foreign key to the primary key in their respective tables.

For example:

```
 CREATE TABLE todo (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    slug TEXT NOT NULL,

    description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

    user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE category (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    name TEXT,
    slug TEXT,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE todo_category (
    todo_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    category_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`todo_id`, `category_id`),

    CONSTRAINT `f_todo_category_todo` FOREIGN KEY (`todo_id`) REFERENCES `todo` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `f_todo_category_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I can create a todo which has many categories. I can also select that todo, or all todos along with all of their respective categories -- and I can do both rather cleanly with only 1-2 queries.

When I try to **UPDATE** a `todo`, I can also update the categories using a **REPLACE INTO** query on the `todo_category` table. I know it will delete and create those rows again, but I think it is fine in this case because generally there won't be more than a hand full of categories. The problem with this approach, however, is that what if new categories weren't added, but were removed? This brings me to my question...

Is there a standard query for doing something like this (update the `todo_category` table to delete id's that aren't present, and add id's that are new -- in one query), or is this where I have to just use code logic and do multiple queries for my own case scenario, such as my example below?

How I'm currently attempting to do it is as follows (which I think is really bad because it requires many queries and many lines of code):

1. **UPDATE** the todo
2. **SELECT** the todo that we just updated in order to use its ID later
3. **SELECT** all the categories corresponding to the ID we got from #2 (we create an array of already existing category ID's from these results)
4. **SELECT** all categories with a matching `todo_id` from #2, as well as with matching category ID's from the ID's sent in the request (these would be the ID's sent by the form that is meant to update this todo and its categories)
5. Do a diff on the category ID's from #3 and the category ID's from #4 to see what is new, what is no longer present (removed), and create two new arrays from those results
6. Do an **INSERT** query to add the new categories in the `todo_category` table to reflect the new ID's
7. Do a **DELETE** query to remove the categories that were no longer present in the request compared to the categories the `todo` currently has

As you can see, that is very granular and requires many queries as well as makes the `Update` method in the code on that Todo model very much larger than all of the other methods, and it makes me feel like there's a better approach.

**EDIT**

Here is my code, albeit incomplete (it's just for reference, though I don't think it matters much cause I explained what I'm doing above):

```
// Update makes changes to an existing item.
func Update(db Connection, title string, description string, slug string, idsFromRequest category.IDList, userID string) (sql.Result, error) {
    // Update the todo
    newSlug := helper.StringToSlug(title, true)
    result, err := db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf(`
        UPDATE %v
        SET title = ?,
            slug = ?,
            description = ?
        WHERE slug = ?
            AND user_id = ?;
    `, table), title, newSlug, description, slug, userID)
    if err != nil {
        return result, err
    }

    // Get the todo to reference its ID
    t, _, err := BySlug(db, newSlug)
    if err != nil {
        return result, err
    }

    // Get the categories the todo currently has
    cats, _, err := category.ByTodoID(db, t.ID)
    if err != nil {
        return result, err
    }

    // Get the ids from all of the categories
    var idsAlreadyExisting []string
    for _, cat := range cats {
        idsAlreadyExisting = append(idsAlreadyExisting, cat.ID)
    }

    // Get the ids to be added (don't yet exist) and the ids to be deleted (not present in the request)
    idsToBeAdded, idsToBeDeleted := diff(idsAlreadyExisting, idsFromRequest)

    // Create the query for adding the category ids for the todo in todo_category
    query := `INSERT INTO todo_category (todo_id, category_id)`
    for i, id := range idsToBeAdded {
        if i == 0 {
            query += ` VALUES`
        }
        query += fmt.Sprintf(` (%s, %s)`, fmt.Sprint(t.ID), id)
        if i == len(idsToBeAdded) - 1 {
            query += ";"
        } else {
            query += ","
        }
    }
    result, err = db.Exec(query)

    // Delete query goes here...

    return result, err
}
```

Comment: Good question... You mention that the categories posted by the user already has an ID in the form? Where do that ID come from originally? Do you have a set of available categories to choose from, or can the user create a complete new category?

Comment: @MichaelK I have a set to choose from, though it would be trivial to create a new category that can be added to that set. And yes, the ID's of the categories that the todo already has will be present in the form while editing, and you can either remove some categories or add more, which will send some more ID's back to the server upon submission of the form.

Comment: Does that mean that the submission from the form already contains ALL category-ID:s that should be connected to the todo?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And depending on what a user does (remove a some categories, or add more new ones), the ID's sent back will be reflected as such. I updated my question with the code for example.

Comment: And step #2 could be excluded, because you probably already have the todo-ID when doing the update?

Comment: Actually no, the sql-driver I'm using does not return an ID on update, only rows affected and last insert ID, but in this case there is no insert going on so I have to query again.

Comment: More specifically on why not, I do the update using the slug, though I cannot use the slug to find the related categories because the `todo_category` table has a foreign key of the id, not slug. I could indeed probably exclude step 2 just by using the id instead of a slug for the update, good point there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier if you used a primary key in your UPDATE statement instead of using `slug` and `user_id`

The todo-ID could be sent on form submission. And since all category-ID:s also are available on form submission, I would probably do something like this:

1. **UPDATE** the table `todo` using the primary key instead of `slug` and `user_id`
2. **INSERT** new categories in table `category` that do not already exist compared to the array of category-ID:s submitted in the form
3. **DELETE** ALL rows in table `todo_category` WHERE todo-ID = the submitted todo-ID
4. **INSERT** rows in table `todo_category` with ALL the category-ID:s submitted from the form, together with the todo-ID

If you need to clean up and delete categories in table `categories` that do not have any relation to any `todo-ID`, you could finish of with a query to delete orphan categories.

Comment: Ah, nice. I didn't think to just simply delete the rows and recreate them using the new category ID's from the request. Much simpler approach and gets the job done with less queries and less code. Plus, there won't be much overhead from deleting/recreating because there's so few categories attached to a todo to begin with; it generally will never exceed a hand full. Also, I am going to use the primary key instead of slug as that too will require one less query, but I need the user_id for verification (don't want someone else editing a todo that isn't theirs). Thanks!

Comment: I'd still like to know if there is a way to do it without deleting. This works great for my case, but what if a todo has 100000 categories in the normal case? Then I think something like this would be bad. What would the solution be then?

Comment: Glad it helped. The steps in my answer are a bit simplified, but I generally use this approach in my projects to minimize complexity and number of queries that tend to follow updates of many-to-many relations. What did you mean with a todo having 10000 people? I assumed one todo belonged to one user only?

Comment: That was a bad example I guess. I can't really think of an example where you'd have 100,000 rows of relationships of 1 table that all need to be deleted/re-created on an update, but hypothetically speaking what if you did need that kind of thing on every update? What kind of a workaround would you do then? Cause I imagine this solution would not be optimal in that case.

Comment: I would probably benchmark and test different solutions and scenarios as there are no given answers if an update or insert/delete approach is better than the other. The best solution depends on so many things... In my experience it's always best to keep the database happy with small, simple and optimized queries. To delete and insert 100000 rows may very well be more efficient than a complex update or procedure.

Comment: Hmm, good advice. Thanks again! (I'm a SQL noob, if you haven't noticed.) I come from the front-end world.